# How to link a sharepoint document library into the template path of microsoft word?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, templates, sharepoint-2013

We have a library for all business templates in our company. However, access is usually performed by directly opening the template via a webbrowser. The outcome is, that instead of opening a new document based on the template, Word or other office programs will open the template. This causes all inexperienced users to save their filled forms as templates all over their hard drives and network drives.

It is not uncommon, that they can't find the saved documents in the aftermath.

I tried to select the document library as path for templates in word, but I get the error message: You can't use an internet-address here.

Is there any known workaround?
Sharepoint 2013 and office 2013

Answer (score 1):

Document Libraries allow you to specify custom template files.  Using these - when you create a document from the template it creates a new one and saves it directly into the library.  They way you do it will almost always lead to the same result because by default when you open the document from SharePoint it want's to save back there to the same file.

To try this - do the following:

1. Create a new document library
2. Open the library and in Ribbon select the "Library" tab, then open
   "List Settings"
3. Select the "Advanced Settings" link
4. Now - you should see the "Document Template" section on the page. 
   you can point to a document in other library by putting the URL
   here. Of use the "edit template" link that will open a blank word
   document that you can edit and then save it back to the library.
5. Once you have template defined - go back to the document library
   view, in the Ribbon select "File" and then hit the drop down arrow
   under "new document" and you should see your template here.
6. Click that - it will open your template - then when you save it - it
   will still save to the library but it won't overwrite your template.

You can add multiple templates - but to do so you need to use SharePoint Designer or Open the library in Windows Explorer.  You just need to store them in the "forms" folder which is hidden by default.

**EDIT**

If you want to keep the templates in place - then add them all to a library, and don't give anyone edit permissions (just read only).  Then they can't save back to that library and overwrite your template.  However I believe my suggestion above will be a bit more user friendly.

Comment: This is an interesting method. However I still have the problem, that an opened template will be saved as a template again. The other drawback is, that I have to make a template in the library for every existing template (roghly 50).

Comment: Not sure what's happening with your template - but if you save it as a normal docx it's still a "template" for SharePoint, and that should fix your issue.   The 2nd part - there are no short cuts there, they have to be moved to take advantage of this part of SharePoint.  It's an upfront cost - once it's done you don't have to worry about it again.